# PyCharm file template date variable doesn't fill 4 digit year on Ubuntu

Tags: python, templates, pycharm, velocity

I'm using file template for python so that when creating new python files, the comments are added by default. My template is as below

```
# Author: Nagabhushan S N
# Last Modified: $DATE
```

On my windows machine, `$DATE` is replaced by `21/08/2020` but on my ubuntu machine, it is `21/08/20`. The difference is only 2 digit year is put. I want it to be 4 digits. Is it possible to make this happen?

Comment: What is the result of the `env | grep LC_TIME` command? What happens if you change it?

Comment: Nothing. There is no environment variable called `LC_TIME`.